# Is there a formula to find out the perimeter of an irregular shape on lattice points when you already know the area?

Tags: area

> Is there a formula to find out the perimeter of an irregular shape on lattice points when you already know the area?

I am asking this as I have a test tomorrow, and one of the questions that could come up is the area/perimeter of an irregular shape on lattice points. I already know how to find out the area using [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem),  however there doesn't seem to be anything on the internet which talks about finding out the area by a formula and when you already know the area. This [website](https://www.sophia.org/tutorials/area-and-perimeter-of-irregular-shapes) could help though. So, is there a formula to find out the perimeter of an irregular shape on lattice points when you already know the area?

Also, is there a way to find out the perimeter of an irregular shape when you already know the area, but the shape isn't on lattice points? Thanks!

[image: Irregular shape on lattice points]

Comment: If the shape is irregular, but all corners are on lattice points, then using the Pythagorean theorem repeatedly is, I think, the best way to calculate the perimeter.

Comment: You take the area, write it down, then turn the page and add the distances between consecutive vertices.

Comment: @Arthur- Use Pythagorean Theorem repeatedly on _what_?

Answer (score 1):

**Use the distance formula repeatedly for each side.**

### Distance Formula

Distance between two points whose coordinates are $(x_1 , y_1)$ and $(y_1 , y_2)$ is given by the formula
$$d = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}
$$

This can be proved using the **Pythagoras theorem**.

**For simplicity, you can set the origin at one end of the sides to simplify the formula each time.**